# Como faço para validar quantas imagens tem dentro de um arquivo TIFF?

Tags: c#, conversão-de-tipo, conversão, jpg

Quero fazer uma validação em C# para quando converter uma imagem de TIFF para JPEG eu consiga saber se todas as imagens foram convertidas, pois o TIFF é um único arquivo que as vezes traz várias imagens dentro dele.

Então às vezes tenho 10 TIFF que Gera 30 JPEG, então para não precisar abrir o TIFF e ir contando eu gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de saber quantas imagens vem no TIFF sem abrir.

Comment: Acho que isto pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668945/convert-tiff-to-jpg-format

Comment: Converter eu consigo, o problema é eu validar se está trazendo a quantidade de imagens certa, pois geralmente são milhares de imagens que eu converto.

Answer (score 2):

Usando o método [GetFrameCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getframecount(v=vs.110).aspx) da classe `Image` é possível saber o número de imagens contidas no arquivo:

```
int numeroImagens = Image.FromFile(@"C:\test.tiff").GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
```